# Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'List<double>'

Tags: c#

```
double indexValues = 0;    
var filterValues = Values as List<double> ?? Values as List<string>;
return (from val in filterValues select indexValues++).ToList();
```

It says,

```
Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'List<double>' and 'List<string>'
```

Here `Values` is `IEnumerable`, Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Comment: Well what type did you expect `filterValues` to be, bearing in mind that that has to be determined at compile-time?

Comment: use normal if else and forget one linear...

Comment: filterValues type based on the input it may List<double> as well as List<string>

Comment: No, it can't. The type is determined at compile-time. To put it another way: if your next line were `double x = filterValues.First();` should that compile or not? You really need to understand the difference between information that is known at compile-time and information which is only available at execution time.

Comment: So what's the declared return type of your method? (It feels like you're still not understanding my point. The type of a variable is specified at compile-time, but it seems you're trying to make it depend on execution-time information.)

Comment: So how would you expect that to work if `Values` is actually a `List<string>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). The reason compiler complaint on this code is that left hand side and right hand site operand types should be the same type. In your code `List<double>` and `List<string>` are different types.

Try to us `is` check or cast with `as` and check if it is not null.

Comment: Although the answer is not wrong ; I found the *solution* given pretty disturbing or incomplete because you say "cast with `as` and check if it is not null" which is basically what he has done with his `as` cast and the use of the null-coalescing operator (which basically checks for null)

Comment: @Sehnsucht I meant separately cast with using of regular if-else. Code given by author even not compile and I gave answer why:)

Comment: I understand what you meant but maybe not everyone will ; a simple example snippet to illustrate wouldn't harm.